# leap year determination

Tags: catalina, calendar, bug

macOS 10.15.4 and Calendar.app 11.0 display February 2020 with 28 days, indicating 2020 is not a leap year. Here's a screenshot, showing January and February 2020; note that February 29 is greyed in the February space, indicating that 29 is not a February day:

[image]

On the other hand, the month display shows a 29-day February:

[image]

Many online sources say 2020 is indeed a leap year. For example, [this Microsoft page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/determine-a-leap-year) contains this procedure for determining leap years:

> **How to determine whether a year is a leap year**
>
> To determine whether a year is a leap year, follow these steps:
>
> > 1. If the year is evenly divisible by 4, go to step 2. Otherwise, go to step 5.
> > 2. If the year is evenly divisible by 100, go to step 3. Otherwise, go to step 4.
> > 3. If the year is evenly divisible by 400, go to step 4. Otherwise, go to step 5.
> > 4. The year is a leap year (it has 366 days).
> > 5. The year is not a leap year (it has 365 days).

Applying this, 2020 is determined to be a leap year, and would have a 29-day February.

Who's right? Maybe this is just a bug in the year calendar display.

Comment: What locale and calendar system do you care if leap year is correct? Apple supports many calendar systems. I’d hate to assume the one I use is the one you care about.

Comment: 2020 *is* a leap year and it would be rather surpring if Apple got it wrong in Catalina only but nobody complained in February. Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Location shows California (where I am). Stock calendar.app (v. 11.0). I'll attach a screenshot to the question.

Comment: I see a Feb 29th in your screenshot, in the same gray Feb 22nd has.

Comment: @nohillside That is exactly correct! I have been mis-reading the calendar display's distinction between M-F days of the week (dark) and Sat-Sun weekend days (grey). Thanks for pointing out my error. I agree that macOS and its calendar.app do show 2020 as a leap year.

Comment: Your top month display shows 29 and the bottom 30 - sounds like PEBKAC and a fresh look / rubber duck debugging can sort this out.

Comment: @bmike You're completely correct. User error _ab initio_.

Comment: The good news is delete works wonders unless you’re ok sharing your initial understanding. I bet others focus on bold text.

Comment: I'll leave it up, thanks. Someone else might benefit from my myopia.

Comment: Wonderful. The winning move is to ask for help and confirmation. I love being wrong for things that aren’t permanent, since it’s always an opportunity to discover _why and how_ I’m wrong and then to grow and learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very easy mistake to make when bold text, dim text collide with a reasonable assumption about something as familiar as a calendar. We train ourselves to expect Sunday first or Monday first.

In this case the solution is to get a screen shot and review the actual data, not what we think we are seeing. I say we since I’ve been in the same situation as OP.

In the images, it’s clear that February 29 was drawn and that there’s no leap year error on Catalina here in the Gregorian calendar setting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Answer is *worded* incorrectly, because the forumala is actually correct.

```
=IF(OR(MOD(A1,400)=0,AND(MOD(A1,4)=0,MOD(A1,100)<>0)),"Leap Year", "NOT a Leap Year")
```

Means if it’s divisible by 400 or 4 with a remainder of zero, it’s a leap year; if it's divisible by 100 it isn't.

- https://www.timeanddate.com/date/leapyear.html
- https://www.mathsisfun.com/leap-years.html

Comment: The year 1900 just called and wants its Feb 29th back :-) Even your links confirm the rules laid out in the question, actually...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year: "Every year that is exactly divisible by four is a leap year, except for years that are exactly divisible by 100, but these centurial years are leap years if they are exactly divisible by 400. For example, the years 1700, 1800, and 1900 are not leap years, but the years 1600 and 2000 are"

Comment: But in any case, 2020 *is* a leap year :-)

Comment: Seriously...I hadn’t even finished typing this thing on my iPad..  My answer is correct.

Comment: It is if you include the full formula, and clarify the differences between division by 4, by 100, and by 400.

Comment: I was just showing the piece where it was dividing by 4 and 400..but the whole formula is good.

Comment: I seem to remember that there was a 29th Feb this year.